# Filter gridview by checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Not sure what I am missing here.  I am filtering a Gridview using multiple dropdowns and text boxes.  However, my checkbox filter is not working.

Here is my main Bind event

```
private void BindGrid(string query, System.Data.CommandType commandType, SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.CommandType = commandType;

    if (parameters.Length > 0)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
    }

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    gvSearch.DataSource = dt;
    gvSearch.DataBind();
}
```

Here is my OnCheckedChange event

```
protected void Check_Filter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<SqlParameter> sqlParameter = new List<SqlParameter>();

    if (Checkbox1.Checked)
    {
        sqlParameter.Add(new SqlParameter("@value", CheckBox1.Checked));
    }

    BindGrid("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Value = @value", System.Data.CommandType.Text, sqlParameter.ToArray());
}
```

The issue is Check_Filter event is not raising at all ?

Let me know if you need any more code.

Comment: What isn't working? Is the checkbox changed event firing? Is `sqlParameter.Add` being called? Is `BindGrid` being called?

Comment: When debugging, it doesn't look like the checkbox change event is firing.

Comment: Is your method subscribed to the appropriate event?

Comment: Is `AutePostback` set to true for the check box?

Comment: DAMMIT.  Autopostback was off.....  Thanks guys